# Get an element from an array using xpath

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I have the following SimpleXML object:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
    (
        [status] => ok
    )

[a] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [b] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [c] => Google
                        [d] => GOOG
                        [e] => http://www.google.com
                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [c] => Yahoo
                        [d] => YHOO
                        [e] => http://www.yahoo.com
                    )

                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [c] => Microsoft
                        [d] => MSFT
                        [e] => http://www.microsoft.com
                    )
```

Given `d` I want to get `e` - Since `b` is an array, is there any way to do this without looping through the entire array?

```
<stk status="ok">
<a>
  <b>
    <c>Yahoo</c>
    <d>YHOO</d>
    <e>http://www.yahoo.com</e>
  </b>

  <b>
    <c>Google</c>
    <d>GOOG</d>
    <e>http://www.google.com</e>
  </b>

  <b>
    <c>Microsoft</c>
    <d>MSFT</d>
    <e>http://www.microsoft.com</e>
  </b>
</a>
</stk>
```

Comment: XPath: `//d/following-sibling::e[1]`?

Comment: Close! This is actually returning all of the `e` values. How could I make it return the `e` value where `d` is, lets day, YHOO?

Comment: If you would share the underlying XML, it would be easier to tell.

Comment: Updated post to show the underlying XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an XPath query asking for the `e` elements that are children of `b` elements having `d` elements with the text `YHOO`.

Remember that `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` will return an array of elements, even if the XPath only finds one: hence `$urls[0]` to get the first (only) one.

```
$xml  = '<stk status="ok"><a><b><c>Yahoo</c><d>YHOO</d><e>http://www.yahoo.com</e></b><b><c>Google</c><d>GOOG</d><e>http://www.google.com</e></b><b><c>Microsoft</c><d>MSFT</d><e>http://www.microsoft.com</e></b></a></stk>';
$stk  = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$urls = $stk->xpath('/stk/a/b[d="YHOO"]/e');
$yhoo = (string) $urls[0];
echo $yhoo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all `//d`.

For each one, evaluate `following-sibling::e[1]`.

I think that's what Marc B meant.